# why magento translation not use PO but use CSV?

Tags: magento

I am wondering why lots of sites use PO to do the translation, but magento uses CSV ? do you think it is better to use CSV than PO ?

Comment: PO is the translation file, you can search .POT, PO, MO ,then you will have a good understanding

Comment: From what I just read about POT, PO & MO files it seems to me that CSV files are far easier to handle for the average Magento user.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is like asking "why Zend Framework and not Symfony?".
Every method has advantages and disadvantages and it may be a mater of choice.
Honestly, I prefer CSV over PO for one simple reason. It can be read in most of the programming languages without issues.